# Java: Copying data from dialog box text field to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, dialog

This project requires that a user inputs data into text fields on a dialog box accessed from a menu bar and places the data from the text fields into a JTable. The problem is that once the user clicks okay on the dialog box after putting the information into the text field, the dialog box is no longer visible, but nothing appears in the JTable. The JTable headers are there, but the info just submitted is not.

It is a camping registration program, and all of the classes compile okay. I am only working on taking information from an RV reservation first, but will eventually do the same for a tent reservation. Here are the classes that correspond to an RV check in. There is an RV constructor that has parameters (String (name), String (check in day), int (days staying), String (leave day), int (site number), int (power needed)). 
First the dialog box class:

```
package campingPrj;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogCheckInRv extends javax.swing.JDialog implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private javax.swing.JTextField nameTxt;
private javax.swing.JTextField dateIn;
private javax.swing.JTextField stayingTxt;
private javax.swing.JTextField siteNumberTxt;
private javax.swing.JTextField checkOutDate;
private javax.swing.JTextField powerTxt;
private javax.swing.JButton okButton;
private javax.swing.JButton cancelButton;
private boolean cancel;
private boolean okay;


public DialogCheckInRv(java.awt.Frame parent) {
    super(parent, true);
    setupDialog();
    setTitle("RV Check In");
}


private void setupDialog() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    nameTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField(27);
    dateIn = new javax.swing.JTextField(25);
    stayingTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField(25);
    siteNumberTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField(27);
    powerTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField(27);

    okButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Ok");
    okButton.addActionListener(this);
    cancelButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.addActionListener(this);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Name Reserving:"));
    panel.add(nameTxt);
    add(panel);

    panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Start Date (mm/dd/yy) :"));
    panel.add(dateIn);
    add(panel);

    panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Days Planning on Staying:"));
    panel.add(stayingTxt);
    add(panel);

    panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Requested Site Number:"));
    panel.add(siteNumberTxt);
    add(panel);

    panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Power Needed (in AMPs):"));
    panel.add(powerTxt);
    add(panel);


    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(okButton);
    panel.add(cancelButton);
    add(panel);

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == okButton) {
        okay = true;
        cancel = false;
        setVisible(false);
    }
    if (event.getSource() == cancelButton) {
        okay = false;
        cancel = true;
        setVisible(false);
    }
}

public boolean isOk() {
    return okay;
}

public boolean isCancel() {
    return cancel;
}

public String getName() {
    return nameTxt.getText();
}

public String getDateIn() {
    return dateIn.getText();
}

public String getDaysStaying() {
    return stayingTxt.getText();
}

public String getCheckOutDate() {
    return checkOutDate.getText();
}

public String getPower() {
    return powerTxt.getText();
}

public String getSiteNumber() {
    return siteNumberTxt.getText();
}

public void clear() {
    nameTxt.setText(null);
    dateIn.setText(null);
    stayingTxt.setText(null);
    dateIn.setText(null);
    powerTxt.setText(null);
    siteNumberTxt.setText(null);
}

}
```

The GUI with the table (where I'm guessing the problem is in the actionPerformed method):

```
 package campingPrj;

 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 import javax.swing.*;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class GUICampingReg extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JMenuItem openSerialFileItem = new JMenuItem("Open Serialized File");
private JMenuItem openTextFileItem = new JMenuItem("Open Text File");
private JMenuItem saveSerialFileItem = new JMenuItem("Save Serialized File");
private JMenuItem saveTextFileItem = new JMenuItem("Save Text File");
private JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
private JMenuItem checkInTentItem = new JMenuItem("Check in tent");
private JMenuItem checkInRVItem = new JMenuItem("Check in RV");
private JMenuItem checkOutItem = new JMenuItem("Date Leaving");

private JTextField nameReservingTxt;
private JTextField dateInTxt;
private JTextField daysStayingTxt;
private JTextField checkOutOnTxt;
private JTextField siteNumberTxt;
private JTextField powerTxt;

private JFrame frame;
private JTable table;
private SiteModel model;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private DialogCheckInRv newRv;

public GUICampingReg() {
    setupFrame();
    newRv = new DialogCheckInRv(this);
    model = new SiteModel();
    table.setModel(model);
}

private void setupFrame() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Camping Registration Program");

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    table = new JTable();

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    fileMenu.add(openSerialFileItem);
    fileMenu.add(openTextFileItem);
    fileMenu.add(saveSerialFileItem);
    fileMenu.add(saveTextFileItem);
    fileMenu.add(exitItem);

    JMenu checkInMenu = new JMenu("Check In");
    checkInMenu.add(checkInRVItem);
    checkInMenu.add(checkInTentItem);

    JMenu checkOutMenu = new JMenu("Check Out");
    checkOutMenu.add(checkOutItem);

    menubar.add(fileMenu);
    menubar.add(checkInMenu);
    menubar.add(checkOutMenu);

    openSerialFileItem.addActionListener(this);
    openTextFileItem.addActionListener(this);
    saveSerialFileItem.addActionListener(this);
    saveTextFileItem.addActionListener(this);
    exitItem.addActionListener(this);
    checkInTentItem.addActionListener(this);
    checkInRVItem.addActionListener(this);
    checkOutItem.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    scrollPane
            .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    table.setToolTipText("");
    table.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            tableMouseClicked();
        }

    });

    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void tableMouseClicked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object pressed = evt.getSource();

    if (pressed == exitItem) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (pressed == openSerialFileItem) {

    }
    if (pressed == openTextFileItem) {

    }
    if (pressed == saveSerialFileItem) {

    }
    if (pressed == saveTextFileItem) {

    }
    if (pressed == checkInTentItem) {

    }
    if (pressed == checkInRVItem) {
        newRv.clear();
        newRv.setVisible(true);
        if (newRv.isOk()) {
            String nameReserving = nameReservingTxt.getText();
            String checkIn = dateInTxt.getText();
            int daysStaying = Integer.parseInt(daysStayingTxt.getText());
            String checkOutOn = checkOutOnTxt.getText();
            int siteNumber = Integer.parseInt(siteNumberTxt.getText());
            int power = Integer.parseInt(powerTxt.getText());
            RV rv = new RV (nameReserving, checkIn, daysStaying, checkOutOn, siteNumber, power);
            model.add(rv);
        }

    }
    if (pressed == checkOutItem) {

    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GUICampingReg();
        }
    });
}

}
```

The site model class:

```
package campingPrj;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class SiteModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ArrayList<Site> listSites;
private String[] columnNames = { "Name Reserving", "Checked in Date",
        "Days Staying", "Site #", "Tenters/RV Power Needed" };

public SiteModel() {
    listSites = new ArrayList<Site>();
}

public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return columnNames[col];
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return listSites.size();
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Object val = null;
    switch (col) {
    case 0:
        val = listSites.get(row).getNameReserving();
        break;
    case 1:
        val = listSites.get(row).getCheckIn();
        break;
    case 2:
        val = listSites.get(row).getDaysStaying();
        break;
    case 3:
        val = listSites.get(row).getSiteNumber();
        break;
    case 4:
        val = listSites.get(row).getCheckOutOn();
        break;

    }
    return val;
}

public Site get(int index) {
    return listSites.get(index);
}

public int indexOf(Site s) {
    return listSites.indexOf(s);
}

public void add(Site s) {
    if (s != null) {
        listSites.add(s);
        fireTableRowsInserted(listSites.size() - 1, listSites.size() - 1);
    }
}

public void add(int index, Site s) {
    if (s != null) {
        listSites.add(index, s);
        fireTableRowsInserted(index, index);
    }
}

public void remove(int index) {
    listSites.remove(index);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(index, index);
    return;
}

public void remove(Site s) {
    remove(indexOf(s));
}

public void saveAsSerialized(String filename) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(listSites);
    os.close();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void loadFromSerialized(String filename) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    listSites = (ArrayList<Site>) is.readObject();
    is.close();
}

}
```

So, how do I get the information to show up in JTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misinterpreting your code, but I don't see where you areextracting the information that the user enters into the dialog. For example here:

```
    if (newRv.isOk()) {
        String nameReserving = nameReservingTxt.getText();
        String checkIn = dateInTxt.getText();
        int daysStaying = Integer.parseInt(daysStayingTxt.getText());
        String checkOutOn = checkOutOnTxt.getText();
        int siteNumber = Integer.parseInt(siteNumberTxt.getText());
        int power = Integer.parseInt(powerTxt.getText());
        RV rv = new RV (nameReserving, checkIn, daysStaying, checkOutOn, siteNumber, power);
        model.add(rv);
    }
```

You appear to be extracting information from the fields held by the GUICampingReg, not by the newRv object. Shouldn't you be calling methods of newRv to extract the data needed to create your RV object?

for example,

```
    if (newRv.isOk()) {
        String nameReserving = newRv.getName();
        String checkIn = newRv.getDateIn();

        // .... etc

        RV rv = new RV (nameReserving, checkIn, daysStaying, checkOutOn, siteNumber, power);
        model.add(rv);
    }
```

Comment: Yes! Wow, I cannot believe I didn't see that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TABmayfield: you're welcome, and glad things are moving forward.